# error:orphaned case y orphaned default al implementar un Switch-case en Java

Tags: java, switch

Estoy realizando un ejercicio con Java que sin embargo me da errores.
Al tratar de compilar el código, me saltan varios errores con el switch-case( case 2: case 3: y default:).
Básicamente la clase consiste en 3 "minijuegos"entre los que puedes elegir. Primero debes de introducir un usuario y una contraseña y después los vuelves a introducir. El programa valida que las 2 varibles coincidan con las de la primera vez, y si lo hacen, dan paso a un Switch-case para poder elegir entre 1 de los 3 juegos. Si no lo hacen, dice que no has podido acceder.
No sé como arreglarlo y sería de gran ayuda que alguien pudiera ayudarme. Muchas gracias.
El error es : "error: orphaned case".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por aquí dejo el código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Resumen{
  public static void main(String args[]){

  Scanner.hola= new Scanner(System.in);
 String nombre= "", usuario= "", contrasena= "",  usuario_2= "", contrasena_2="", cadena_1="", cadena_2="", cadena_3="", cadena_4="";
 short parametro= 0, renta_1= 500, renta_2= 1500, renta_3= 4000,  a= 0, b= 0, eleccion_renta= 0, resultado_renta= 0, tope= 0, desde_1=0, hasta_1=0, n=0, desde_2= 0, hasta_2= 0, n_2= 0;


 System.out.println("BIENVENIDO A MINI-JUEGOS INC");
 System.out.println("¿como te llamas?:");
nombre= hola.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Encantado,"   +     nombre);

 System.out.print("¿Usuario? :");
 usuario= hola.nextLine();
 System.out.print("¿Contrasena? : ");
contrasena=hola.nextLine();
 System.out.print("Vuelve a escribir tu usuario:  ");
 usuario_2=hola.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Vuelve a escribir tu contrasena:  ");
 contrasena_2=hola.nextLine();

  if(usuario.equals(usuario_2) && contrasena.equals(contrasena_2)){

   System.out.println("ENHORABUENA, HAS ENTRADO");
   System.out.println(" Hay 3 juegos : 1-OPERACIONES RENTA Y JUEGOS, 2- FIBONACCI CON FOR, 3- CREACIÓN DE CADENAS CON WHILE");
   System.out.print("¿Cual quieres elegir?: ");
   parametro= hola.nextShort();

    switch(parametro){

   case 1 :  System.out.println("¿Quieres igualar las rentas, suprimir la renta baja y darsela a la alta o suprimir la alta , la mitad de la media y darsela a la baja?");
                  eleccion_renta= hola.nextInt();

                      if(eleccion_renta == 1){
                     resultado_renta= (renta_1 + renta_2 + renta_3) /3;
                    System.out.println("OK, el resultado de la renta es"   +       resultado_renta);

                  } else if(eleccion_renta == 2){
                    resultado_renta= renta_3 + renta_1;
                     System.out.println("OK, el resultado de la renta es "   +     resultado_renta   +      "euros");
         
                 }  else if(eleccion_renta == 3){
                   resultado_renta= renta_2 /2 + renta_1 + renta_3;
                  System.out.println("OK, el resultado de la renta es "   +     resultado_renta  +   "euros");

             }  else{
                 System.out.println("ERROR");
                 break;

   case 2 :    System.out.print("Dime el primer termino: " );
                   a= hola.nextShort();
                    System.out.print("Dime el segundo termino: ");
                    b= hola.nextShort();
                   System.out.println("Dime hasta cual quieres contar:  " );
                   tope=hola.nextShort();
                
                    for(i= a; i<=tope; i+=5 ){
                    if(i < tope){

                  System.out.println(a + ",");

                }else{

               System.out.println(a);

                  c= a+b;
                 a=b;
                  b=c;
                  break;       

     case 3 :  System.out.print("Introduce una cadena");
                   cadena_1= hola.nextLine();
                System.out.println("¿Desde que caracter quieres hacer otra?:");
                   desde_1=hola.nextShort();
                System.out.println("¿Hasta que caracter quieres crear otra?:");
                 hasta_1= hola.nextShort();
                cadena_2= cadena_1.substring(desde_1, hasta_1);
                  n= cadena_2.length();
                 System.out.println("Tu nueva cadena es "  +    cadena_2      +       ", y tiene "    +   n    +       "caracteres");
                 System.out.println("Inserta otra cadena, por favor: ");
                 cadena_3= hola.nextLine();
                  System.out.println("Desde donde quieres crear otra: ");
                  desde_2= hola.nextShort();
                   System.out.println("Hasta donde quieres crear otra: ");
                  hasta_2= hola.nextShort();
                 cadena_4= cadena_3.substring(desde_2, hasta_2);
                 n_2= cadena_4.length();

                 System.out.println("Esta cadena es  "       +         cadena_4    +       "y tiene"     +       n_2         +        "caracteres");

                short i = n;
                while(i <= n_2){
              if(i < n_2){
                System.out.print(i + ", ");

         }else{
          System.out.print(i);
           i++;
                 break;

   default :   System.out.print("SORRY, ya no hay mas opciones ");
                   break;






}  }else{

   System.out.print("UPPS, usuario o contrasena incorrecto ");


}
                                     


}
               



}

             

}



 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo revisando tu código veo que tienes diferentes tipos de error. El error en particular que mencionas "orphaned case" se debe a que las llaves del for y el while están mal. A continuación te dejo el código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Resumen {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner hola = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombre = "", usuario = "", contrasena = "", usuario_2 = "", contrasena_2 = "", cadena_1 = "", cadena_2 = "", cadena_3 = "", cadena_4 = "";
    int parametro = 0, renta_1 = 500, renta_2 = 1500, renta_3 = 4000, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, eleccion_renta = 0, i = 0, resultado_renta = 0, tope = 0, desde_1 = 0, hasta_1 = 0, n = 0, desde_2 = 0, hasta_2 = 0, n_2 = 0;

    System.out.println("BIENVENIDO A MINI-JUEGOS INC");
    System.out.println("¿como te llamas?:");
    nombre = hola.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Encantado," + nombre);

    System.out.print("¿Usuario? :");
    usuario = hola.nextLine();
    System.out.print("¿Contrasena? : ");
    contrasena = hola.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Vuelve a escribir tu usuario:  ");
    usuario_2 = hola.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Vuelve a escribir tu contrasena:  ");
    contrasena_2 = hola.nextLine();

    if (usuario.equals(usuario_2) && contrasena.equals(contrasena_2)) {

        System.out.println("ENHORABUENA, HAS ENTRADO");
        System.out.println(" Hay 3 juegos : 1-OPERACIONES RENTA Y JUEGOS, 2- FIBONACCI CON FOR, 3- CREACIÓN DE CADENAS CON WHILE");
        System.out.print("¿Cual quieres elegir?: ");
        parametro = hola.nextInt();

        switch (parametro) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("¿Quieres igualar las rentas, suprimir la renta baja y darsela a la alta o suprimir la alta , la mitad de la media y darsela a la baja?");
                eleccion_renta = hola.nextShort();
                if (eleccion_renta == 1) {
                    resultado_renta = (renta_1 + renta_2 + renta_3) / 3;
                    System.out.println("OK, el resultado de la renta es" + resultado_renta);

                } else if (eleccion_renta == 2) {
                    resultado_renta = renta_3 + renta_1;
                    System.out.println("OK, el resultado de la renta es " + resultado_renta + "euros");

                } else if (eleccion_renta == 3) {
                    resultado_renta = renta_2 / 2 + renta_1 + renta_3;
                    System.out.println("OK, el resultado de la renta es " + resultado_renta + "euros");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.print("Dime el primer termino: ");
                a = hola.nextShort();
                System.out.print("Dime el segundo termino: ");
                b = hola.nextShort();
                System.out.println("Dime hasta cual quieres contar:  ");
                tope = hola.nextShort();

                for (i = a; i <= tope; i += 5) {
                    if (i < tope) {

                        System.out.println(a + ",");

                    } else {

                        System.out.println(a);

                        c = a + b;
                        a = b;
                        b = c;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.print("Introduce una cadena");
                 hola.nextLine();
                cadena_1 = hola.next();

             
                System.out.println("¿Desde que caracter quieres hacer otra?:");
                desde_1 = hola.nextShort();
                System.out.println("¿Hasta que caracter quieres crear otra?:");
                hasta_1 = hola.nextShort();
                cadena_2 = cadena_1.substring(desde_1, hasta_1);
                n = cadena_2.length();
                System.out.println("Tu nueva cadena es " + cadena_2 + ", y tiene " + n + "caracteres");
                System.out.println("Inserta otra cadena, por favor: ");
                cadena_3 = hola.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Desde donde quieres crear otra: ");
                desde_2 = hola.nextShort();
                System.out.println("Hasta donde quieres crear otra: ");
                hasta_2 = hola.nextShort();
                cadena_4 = cadena_3.substring(desde_2, hasta_2);
                n_2 = cadena_4.length();

                System.out.println("Esta cadena es  " + cadena_4 + "y tiene" + n_2 + "caracteres");

                i = n;
                while (i <= n_2) {
                    if (i < n_2) {
                        System.out.print(i + ", ");

                    } else {
                        System.out.print(i);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.print("SORRY, ya no hay mas opciones ");
                break;

        }
    } else {

        System.out.print("UPPS, usuario o contrasena incorrecto ");

    }

}
```

}